# Kernel debugging Windows 7 through serial port

Tags: debugging, windows-7, driver, windbg, device-driver

I have debugged drivers on VM (pipe connection) with Windows 7. Now I want to debug a driver in a laptop with Windows 7 (x64) but the WinDbg keeps waiting forever for the connection:

> Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger  Version 6.7.0005.1 Copyright (c)
>   Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Opened \.\com1 Waiting to reconnect...

In the target laptop I boot with this BCD entry:

```
Identificador           {current}

device                  partition=C:

path                    \windows\system32\winload.exe

description             DebugEntry

locale                  es-ES

inherit                 {bootloadersettings}

recoverysequence        {b3c5a314-b064-11df-ba01-a8d3a819aefa}

recoveryenabled         Yes

bootdebug               Yes

osdevice                partition=C:

systemroot              \windows

resumeobject            {b3c5a312-b064-11df-ba01-a8d3a819aefa}

nx                      OptIn

detecthal               Yes

debug                   Yes
```

The debug settings on target are:

```
C:\windows\system32>bcdedit /dbgsettings
debugtype               Serial
debugport               1
baudrate                115200
```

Baudrate is the same in both host and target because I launch the debugger this way:

> windbg.exe -k com:port=COM**1**,baud=**115200**

The cable works for kernel debugging because I have used it before, in fact when I monitor the COM1 in the target machine I can see the polling messages comming from the WinDbg and even the Control+Break message... but nothing happens.

The serial port, as expected, is enabled in both BIOS settings.

Also, it seems that Windows is not waiting fot the timeout on COM 1 at boot time, it starts normally without a delay...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure that your laptop has a "real" COM-port, not a USB-COM or PCMCI-COM?

Comment: Not really, the [specs](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13616_ca/13616_ca.PDF) just say "Serial Port". Serial port properties in "Device manager" doesn't help (me) too much. Maybe opening the laptop case?

Comment: As an alternative you can use a 1394 port (firewire) for debugging. It works much faster.

Comment: Did you get this work? I have same problem.

Comment: How did you monitor the messages on target machine? Also you mention that windows should wait during boot, is this true? I did not find anything about this. I've tested successfully the connection of two PCs via putty.

Comment: Hi Wakan, It did not work because it was not a real COM-port. It works on other PCs. Are you testing kernel COM connection with a network tool?

Comment: Hi @zapador I am testing it under XEN. Here is my problem described in details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30049300/after-booting-to-kernel-with-debugging-enabled-the-com1-port-is-missing-on-windo

Comment: Humm, have you tried "bcdedit /bootdebug on" ?

Answer (score 0):

on your target machine please verify if the com port is working properly. goto device manager and check the com port properties. it might have been disabled or its resources might be allocated to some other device.

Comment: How to check if resources of COM1are allocated for another device?